# Combining shapes in SVG before applying a filter to resultant shape

Tags: svg

I'm currently in the process of drawing a logo in SVG.

The logo drawing is perfectly fine, however I want to apply a filter to my shapes. Now the letters in the logotype are made up of separate shapes.

My question is how do I best combine said shapes into one resultant shape? I've found some things about feBlend and veUnion but information is scattered and sparse and these are my first steps into the wonderful world of SVG.

Besides unioning two shapes into one before applying my filter I'd also want (in the case of my example the n in the word qabana) to subtract certain shapes from a shape before applying my filter.

Example of the SVG I am working on: http://buffer.io/~simon/qabana-svg/handmade-stackoverflow.svg (this should immediately show you the issues I'm having).

Also, any bonus tips on how to improve my SVG in that file are gladly heard.

Answer (score 3):

veUnion isn't implemented in any browser at this point in time. If you want to merge two or more shapes to a single path you can use a vector graphics editor (e.g Inkscape or Illustrator). If you want to group elements, use a <g> element, and apply the filter to that instead.